# PHP undefined Error while passing data from Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Simply i want to pass Numeric id to Php page and Using $_POST['id'] i want use it, But Getting Undefined error. check screen shot https://i.stack.imgur.com/04Ydd.jpg and check code below

===>edit.php

```
  $('#update').click(function(){
           var serialData = new FormData($("#regForm")[0]), 
               s = location.search.split('='), 
              searchId = s[s.length-1];

              console.log(serialData);
              console.log(searchId);
         serialData.append('id',9);
        $.ajax({
            method:'POST', 
            url:'update.php',
            dataType:'json', 
            data:  {id:9},
            success:function(jsonObj){
            console.log(jsonObj);
          }
        });
     });
```

==>update.php

```
             <?php 
                 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

                  var_dump($_POST['id']);
                         exit();

             }
             ?>
```

Comment: This is still pretty much the same question you asked here already, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56166412/post-does-not-work-does-not-give-data-passed-from-ajax

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$\_POST does not work does not give data passed from ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56166412/post-does-not-work-does-not-give-data-passed-from-ajax)

Comment: @Purefan i want answer not justification

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to change the **id** value to send in parameter to the dynamic value from the `location.search`

Also think about adding `e.preventDefault();` because you work on form submission.

I think that `serialData` can be removed cause it doesn't have affect the current code logic

Here is the working script

```
<script>
    $('#update').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var s = location.search.split('=');
            var searchId = s[s.length-1];

            // Verify the current ID passed on search parameter
            console.log(searchId);
        $.ajax({
            method:'POST', 
            url:'update.php',
            dataType:'json', 
            data:  { 'id': searchId },
            success:function(jsonObj){
                console.log(jsonObj);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```